# Component multiple times same instance in the same page

Tags: angular

Can I show a component multiple times in a page but always the same instance of my component in Angular?

I have a filter form component and I would like to show Teo same filters, one of then on the top and the other on the bottom, and when the user fill the form on the top, the form on the bottom must have the same values selected. And I thought in if it was possible to show the same component twice but same instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more description like what you want to achieve? So that others can help you easily.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. Every time you use your custom component selector, it will create a new instance of that component. But you can try moving the component state and/or business logic from the component to [Angular Services](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). This way you can sync states of multiple components if that is what you are trying to achieve. You can also look into the state management tools for complex use-cases.

Comment: I am going to try. I think that solve my issue. Thanks in advance.